# DOMDocument оборачивает в блок при сохранении

Tags: php, domdocument

```
$html = 'text';
($dom = new DOMDocument)->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_NOWARNING|LIBXML_NOERROR|LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo "<textarea>".$dom->saveHTML()."</textarea>";
```

Почему при сохранении, содержимое оборачивается в блок `<p>` и как этого избежать?

Comment: В какой блок, как выглядит исходный HTML?

Comment: Поправил код в примере

Comment: Этого вероятно никак не избежать, так как структура должна содержать какой-то корневой элемент. Так как в строке `text` его нет - либа добавляет его самостоятельно. Избавиться можно с помощью `strip_tags()` например или чего-то похожего по логике.

Comment: Можно так попробовать $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement) в этом случае будет сохраняться содержимое корневого элемента

Comment: Не работает....

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю, сделать сначала проверку, есть ли оборачивающий тег в исходной строке, и в зависимости от этого сохранять HTML целиком или брать только внутреннюю часть корневого тега. Для этого сделаем функцию `DOMInnerHTML`

```php
<?php
$html = 'text';

function DOMInnerHTML(DOMNode $element){ 
    $innerHTML = ''; 
    $children  = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) 
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    return $innerHTML; 
}
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$hasRootTag = '<' === substr(trim($html), 0, 1);
($dom = new DOMDocument)->loadHTML($html,LIBXML_NOWARNING|LIBXML_NOERROR|LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
echo "<textarea>",
    $hasRootTag ? $dom->saveHTML() : DOMinnerHTML($dom->documentElement),
    "</textarea>";
```